# Request Data from Database and Check with if() condition but the result show even if() condition not meet

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do something like after user click the button, store data in database and than request that data to check with if condition, if the condition is meet or true, the button should disappear.

**Storing Data is success but if() condition is wrong when i use the stored data to check.**

This is the part that i want to check using if()

```
<? 
    $usercheck = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM wallets WHERE wallet = $wallet  ");
    if($usercheck['s1'] == 0){
    $res = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM shortlink WHERE shortid = 1 ");
        while($row = $res->fetch_array()){
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-2"><? echo $row['shortname']; ?></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><? echo $row['shortreward']; ?> <i class="fab fa-viacoin"></i></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><a href="shortlink.php?claim=<? echo $row['shortid']; ?>" ><button class="btn-primary" name="claim">Claim</button></a></div>                  
    <? } } ?>
```

The expect output is if($usercheck['s3'] == 0)is correct button should show but if($usercheck['s3'] == 0) is wrong button shouldn't be show

Comment: Try putting 0 in single quotes like '0'. There is a possibility that PHP is considering 0 as false and the data you are getting is number or string.

Comment: @Danish Hakim Khan I try put it like '0' as you said, but it get worst, even condition is meet, button disappear.

Answer (score 0):

After i add single code at $wallet in sql statement and do one more while loop, the problem solved :D

```
<? 
        $usercheck = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM wallets WHERE wallet = '$wallet'  ");
        while($row = $usercheck->fetch_assoc()){
           $s = $row['s1'];
       }
       if($s == 0){
        $res = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM shortlink WHERE shortid = 1 ");
            while($row = $res->fetch_array()){
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-2"><? echo $row['shortname']; ?></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><? echo $row['shortreward']; ?> <i class="fab fa-viacoin"></i></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><a href="shortlink.php?claim=<? echo $row['shortid']; ?>" ><button class="btn-primary" name="claim">Claim</button></a></div>                  
        <? } } ?>
```